# SendKeys.Send doesn't work when ALT key is hooked (c#)

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-hook

I am able to hook(Global Keyboard hook) ALT key in a winform(c#) application. The code is given below.

```
if ((ModifierKeys == Keys.Alt) && Keys.P == (Keys) vkCode)
{
     SendKeys.Send("Test");
     //MessageBox.Show("test");
     return (IntPtr) 1;
}
```

If I comment out SendKeys line and uncomment MessageBox line then I can see the messagebox if Alt+P is pressed. But SendKeys.Send doesn't work. Why? But if instead of Alt key if I hook Control or Shift key then there is no problem with SendKeys Command.

Comment: Try SendKeys.Send("Pest") to see this go wrong in a spectacular way.

Answer (score 1):

`SendKeys.Send` send key press.
Actually it does work.
But when it send pressed keys <kbd>Alt+T</kbd> <kbd>Alt+E</kbd> <kbd>Alt+S</kbd> <kbd>Alt+T</kbd> cause you pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>. That's why you see no results

Comment: How do I overcome it?

Comment: @jeff try this http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/ here you can make keyup keydown events too